# SQL Server Management Studio crashes on running query

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My SQL Server Management Studio is crashing every time I am running a query.

I am getting following logs:

```
  <entry>
    <record>816</record>
    <time>2024/03/29 15:31:44.769</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Loading UI library</description>
    <guid>{67909B06-91E9-4F3E-AB50-495046BE9A9A}</guid>
    <hr>800a006f</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>817</record>
    <time>2024/03/29 15:31:44.769</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Error loading UI library for package (null). HrLoadNativeUILibrary failed with 0x800a006f.</description>
  </entry>
```

```
  <entry>
    <record>819</record>
    <time>2024/03/29 15:31:44.770</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Failed to find CTMENU resource &apos;#1000&apos; in loaded UI library.</description>
  </entry>
```

Comment: You say running a query, so a *specific* one? What is that query? What version of SSMS?

Comment: Ssms version: 20.0.70.0

And its crashes directly if I click on new Query or Table-> Select Top 1000 -> Run

Comment: Either repair or uninstall/reinstall SSMS and any versions of Visual Studio you have installed.

Comment: @AlanSchofield already done multiple times with different version